# Step based unit testing

Tags: unit-tests

I've just joined a startup and would like to add some automated testing for some basic processes. I'd like something that's step based, i.e. run a step, test the output in some arbitrary way, and then proceed to the next step and do the same. For example:

- use an app (that has a headless mode) to generate a 3D model
- spin up a system to render an image of said model
- compare the image generated to a pre-existing image to determine overall success.

Each of these steps requires a different tool, whatever system I use should be able to run these tools via a command line. Is there such a system?

Comment: In your example, how is it arbitrary?

Comment: The output would be something that could be fed into another command that would return a 1 or 0. The example I had was an image diff tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correct, you want a system for build and test coordination.

That's basically a Continuous Integration Pipeline.
One popular and easy tool for it is [Jenkins Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/), which allows you to create linked steps which runs some commands (like build, deploy artifacts and test) and it is able to use the outputs as input for further steps.

There is also a plugin called [Blue Ocean](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/05/26/introducing-blue-ocean/) to visualize the steps of a pipeline execution on the browser.

Setting up an efficient CI pipeline is a considerable effort, but the benefits are great, because a complex process can be automatically executed and easily expanded, providing fast feedback.